# How to Process Strings of Nodes to get their Connections?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string

I'm doing some work on node trees and I'm stuck with this issue.
This list contains all the information of a tree:

```
connections = ['Module/Expr/ListComp/BinOp/Name/id/i/',
           'Module/Expr/ListComp/BinOp/Sub/',
           'Module/Expr/ListComp/BinOp/Num/0.5/',
           'Module/Expr/ListComp/comprehension/Name/id/i/',
           'Module/Expr/ListComp/comprehension/Name/id/inp/']
```

I need to convert this into:

```
{'Module':'Expr', 'Expr':'ListComp', 'ListComp':'BinOp comprehension', 
'BinOp':'Name Sub Num', 'Name':'id', 'id':'i', 'Num':'0.5', 
'comprehension':'Name', 'Name':'id', 'id':'i inp'}
```

The goal is to parse the connections into a dictionary of structure `{'parent':'child(s)'}`. In order to do this I have already tried this:

```
rules = {}
connections_list = [[word for word in path.split("/") if word] for path in connections]

for path in connections_list:
    for i, word in enumerate(path):
        same_level = [y[i+1] for y in connections_list if len(connections_list) > i+1]
        if same_level:
            unique_on_level = list(set(same_level))
            rules.update({word:" ".join(unique_on_level)})
        else:
            pass
    break
print(rules)
```

With an output:

```
{'Module': 'Expr',
 'Expr': 'ListComp',
 'ListComp': 'BinOp comprehension',
 'BinOp': 'Num Sub Name'}
```

I can't figure out a way of doing this, the issue here happens around the last nodes but I don't know how to solve it, any idea about how to fix this?

Comment: This looks like an X-Y problem: *why* are you parsing this into such an awkward notation?  You're trying to express a tree: why are you not solving the overall problem with a graph?

Answer (score 2):

First create a mapping of parent to children nodes, and then remove the dupes.

```
rules = {}
for connection in connections:
    parts = connection.rstrip("/").split("/")
    for parent, child in zip(parts, parts[1:]):
        if parent not in rules:
            rules[parent] = []
        rules[parent].append(child)

rules = {k: " ".join({}.fromkeys(v)) for k, v in rules.items()}
```

Comment: But this method won't append nodes with the same name, right? Just in case there are two different nodes (on different levels) with the same name

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, can you give an example?

Comment: If there are nodes on different levels with the same name which should appear separately in the output, it can't be a dictionary; a dictionary cannot have duplicate keys like `{'id': 'i', 'id': 'i inp'}`

Comment: @sabik that's True, have you any idea of what can I do in these cases?

Comment: BTW, as a simplification, rather than using `[]`, `append` and then `fromkeys` to get the unique children, we could use `set` (if the order doesn't matter) or a `dict` with `None` values (if order does matter).

Comment: As someone else commented, what are you ultimately trying to achieve? This doesn't seem like a natural notation for this data... However, if you do need it in roughly this form, a list of tuples would probably be the closest: `[('id', 'i'), ('id', 'i inp')]`

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@wim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim)'s answer and the comments, I think this should work:

```
from collections import defaultdict

rule_data = defaultdict(set)
for connection in connections:
    parts = connection.rstrip("/").split("/")
    for level, (parent, child) in enumerate(zip(parts, parts[1:])):
        rule_data[level, parent].add(child)

rules = [
    (parent, " ".join(sorted(children)))
    for (_level, parent), children in rule_data.items()
]
```

Notes:

- Using `set` discards the order of the children; if it's important, we can instead use a `dict` (or, for compatibility with older versions of Python, `OrderedDict`):

  - `rule_data = defaultdict(dict)`
  - `rule_data[level, parent][child] = None`
  - `(parent, " ".join(children))`
- I sort the children for stability of the output, so that unit tests can work easily and so any downstream processing doesn't see spurious changes.
- As [@Prune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4785185/prune) noted, this doesn't seem like a natural representation for the data:

  - What are you ultimately trying to achieve?
  - The `rule_data` intermediate variable here may be more useful in further processing than the final form...
  - If any of the connections contain spaces, the output will be ambiguous.

Comment: level + name is not a unique identifier.  consider  `/a/x/sub1` and `/b/x/sub2`.  if uniqueness is required (O.P. doesn't clarify yet), might need to use the whole parent prefix.

Comment: True; we need clarification whether those should be combined or kept separate.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, uniqueness is a requirement in this case, actually I like the method you use, I think it needs few changes to be exactly what I need. The issue is that node `id` f.ex. appears three times in the connections but are different nodes, because they aren't in the same level.

Answer (score 1):

```
connections = ['Module/Expr/ListComp/BinOp/Name/id/i/',
               'Module/Expr/ListComp/BinOp/Sub/',
               'Module/Expr/ListComp/BinOp/Num/0.5/',
               'Module/Expr/ListComp/comprehension/Name/id/i/',
               'Module/Expr/ListComp/comprehension/Name/id/inp/']

splitted_conns = [conn.strip('/').split('/') for conn in connections]
res = {}
for conn in splitted_conns:
    for root, child in zip(conn[:-1], conn[1:]):
        res[root] = res.get(root, set()) | {child}
print(res)
```

output:

> {'Module': {'Expr'}, 'Expr': {'ListComp'}, 'ListComp': {'BinOp', 'comprehension'}, 'BinOp': {'Sub', 'Num', 'Name'}, 'Name': {'id'}, 'id': {'inp', 'i'}, 'Num': {'0.5'}, 'comprehension': {'Name'}}

Something like this? Your expected output contains duplicate node "id", I suposse that it's a mistake, it's doesn't?

About the solution, I've decided use a set for each group un children, so we can avoid fails with nodes that contain a space in its name. Moreover, with sets is easy to avoid duplicates. If you want to convert each set in a space separated string, yo can try this:

```
{k: ' '.join(v) for k, v in res.items()}
```

Comment: This creates 2*N temporary set objects for N nodes, which are garbage collected immediately afterward. Needlessly inefficient - that's a relatively expensive object to allocate in Python.

Comment: @wim change '|' operator for update method of sets, should solve this problem.
for conn in splitted_conns:
    for root, child in zip(conn[:-1], conn[1:]):
        if root not in res:
            res[root] = {child}
        else:
            res[root].add(child)

Comment: Yep, that would be better and more Pythonic.

Comment: I need it to contain 'duplicate' nodes, (f.ex: `id`) because in fact they are not duplicates but two different nodes (`A/B/id` !=`A/id`) becuse they're at different levels. Anyways thanks for the response, I think I can now figurate out a way of fixing this